# IE10 not responding to an input element change

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

I have a jsfiddle here - http://jsfiddle.net/w9XLn/1/ - with a simple input and a change handler:

HTML

```
 <input id="helpQ" type="text">
```

jQuery

```
$(function() {
    $('input#helpQ').change(function(e) {
       console.log("helpQ changed");
    });
});
```

When you enter some text into the field and hit Enter, the console.log message appears, as expected, for Firefox, Chrome, and Safari, but not for IE (I'm running IE10). Does anyone know why IE is being so difficult?

Thanks

Comment: Traditionally the change event happened when an element lost focus, and in your case pressing Enter doesn't change the focus. I wasn't aware until I read your question that pressing Enter would trigger it in any browser (at least, not when the text input in question isn't in a form where Enter would submit).

Comment: Yes, you've got the answer.  In this case IE was doing the right thing by not recognizing Enter as an onchange trigger and everyone else was being too lenient.  To make this work in IE I need to catch keydown, check if it's 13, and if so read the value of the field.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function(){
    $('input#helpQ').change(function(e){
        console.log("helpQ changed")
    })
    // Help IE10 because it doesn't trigger change until field loses focus.
    $('input#helpQ').keydown(function(e){
        if(e.which == 13) $(this).change()
    })
})
```

Note that in some browsers `console.log()` throws an exception when the console is not open.